# Synchronize on Lazy Load Getter

Tags: java, lazy-loading, synchronized

Since I found no question covering this topic, I thought I'd share my solution to the following scenario. The answer may be obvious, but I took the long route to find out. :) I'd appreciate feedback to both the question and answer as well as other solutions.

**Scenario:**

Suppose you have a multi-threaded program and want a database connection (or some other shared object) for some functionality in your program while other parts of your program don't need it at all. There should only ever be one connection to the db though.

At the same time, you want to detect db connection loss and try to reconnect on the fly.

To cover that, you implement a lazy load pattern "getter" that also checks connection validity before returning the connection object.

Your code may look like this:

```
public class Main {
  private DB _db;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().start();
  }

  private void start() {
    // Program code goes here
    // You create several threads, some of which may call getDB() whenever they need DB access
  }

  public DB getDB() {
    if (_db == null) {
      _db = getDBConnection();
    } else if (!_db.isConnectionValid()) {
      /*
       * DB connection is not valid anymore. Let's close it and
       * try to get a new connection.
       */
      _db.close();
      _db = getDBConnection();
    }

    return _db;
  }

  private DB getDBConnection() {
    DB db;

    // Obtain a new connection...
    ...

    return db;
  }
}
```

**The problem**:

Several threads may try to obtain a db connection at nearly the same time. It is even possible that several connects co-exist when some classes keep references to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Several threads may try to obtain a db connection at nearly the same time. It is even possible that several connects co-exist when some classes keep references to them.

In that case you need a pool as you can obtain multiple different instances. There are many DatabaseConnection pools available and some JDBC drivers have their own. I suggest you use the one which comes with the JDBC driver or use C3P0 or the like to act as Database connection pool.

More specifically you need to take a connection (not just get it) in a way that another thread cannot get the same connection.  A trivial example is to use a Queue.

```
private final Queue<DB> freeDBs = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

public DB acquireDB() {
    DB db = freeDBs.poll();
    if (db != null && db.isConnectionValid()) 
        return db;
    if (db != null)
        db.close();
    return getDBConnection();
}

public void release(DB db) {
    if (freeDBs.size() >= MAX_FREE_SIZE)
        db.close();
    else
        freeDBs.add(db);
}
```

Comment: Could this be combined with the `Semaphore` class? And is it reasonable to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Synchronization can be used to avoid creating several connections at the same time. If two (or more) threads call it at nearly the same time, one of them blocks (waits) until the other finishes. This ensures the second thread gets the connection that was just created by the first thread instead of establishing another connection.

I first tried to synchronize on the object like this:

```
public DB getDB() {
  synchronized (_db) {
    if (_db == null) {
      _db = getDBConnection();
    } else if (!_db.isConnectionValid()) {
      /*
       * DB connection is not valid anymore. Let's close it and
       * try to get a new connection.
       */
      _db.close();
      _db = getDBConnection();
    }
  }

  return _db;
}
```

The problem here is, that doesn't work with lazy loading. You can't synchronize on `null` (you get a `NullPointerException`), but there is no object yet on the first call of `getDB()`.

The solution is to synchronize on the whole method:

```
public synchronized DB getDB() {
  if (_db == null) {
    _db = getDBConnection();
  } else if (!_db.isConnectionValid()) {
    /*
     * DB connection is not valid anymore. Let's close it and
     * try to get a new connection.
     */
    _db.close();
    _db = getDBConnection();
  }


  return _db;
}
```

Additionally, you need to make sure no other methods access the private field `_db` or call `getDBConnection()` directly. That would not be synchronized anymore.

Your classes should not keep references to the connection as that prevents garbage collection on dead connection objects. Calling the getter too often is not suggested either though, as each get may issue a query to check connection validity (depending on the driver). It's probably ok if each method keeps a reference during it's execution (unless it executes for ages).

Comment: All this may be fine as a learning experience, but what you really want in production is a serious **connection pool** implementation that will take care of the issues you are pointing out here as well as a great range of other issues you are about to find out. `boneCP` is my current favorite.

Comment: You still have the problem that multiple threads can obtain the same connection.

Answer (score 2):

Well here's my 2c:

First off, regarding the Object instance you use to do synchronization: if you use the _db object that's bad in the sense where you won't get what you want. The idea here is to make sure that if multiple threads try to create a _db instance "at the same time" (as far as the JDK Process is concerned), once one of those threads creates one instance, the other threads should immediately be aware that that instance exists and not try to create another. Now, if you synchronize the block of code on that very instance we're trying to have synchronized between threads, even if said instance would never be null, you'd still be in a race condition situation where two threads each manage to create an instance of _db, and since the code block is synchronized on that instance, none of the threads will be blocked by the lock, as there's indeed 2 separate locks.
Obviouslly it's better to synchronize the whole method. This is equivalent to writing

```
public DB getDB() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (_db == null) {
                _db = getDBConnection();
            } else if (!_db.isConnectionValid()) {
                /*
                 * DB connection is not valid anymore. Let's close it and
                 * try to get a new connection.
                 */
                _db.close();
                _db = getDBConnection();
            }
            return _db;
        }
    }
```

All threads calling the method that creates the _db instance will "fight" over the same lock (the instance of the Main class) so you can be sure that once a thread acquires that lock the others will block until that thread finishes, and then, when it's their turn to execute the method, the if check will prevent them from creating a second instance of the _db object.

Now, another issue is weather you really want to have the same _db instance across multiple threads. This question is really reduced to weather _db is thread safe, or in other words, is it stateless? If it's stateful and shared by multiple threads, and if that state is not guarded against multi-thread calls, you will get weird behavior and even errors. For example: the JDBC Connection object is NOT thread safe, due to the fact that it contains state about things such as transactions, which can be altered indescribably if multiple threads access the same JDBC Connection at the same time. Due to this, it is advised to use some degree of (Object Instance) isolation when using JDBC Connections in a multi threaded environment. Either you plain old make a new JDBC Connection instance for each thread or you make just one, but then inside each thread it will be kept as a ThreadLocal field so that each thread really gets his own instance which only he himself will alter/access.

Another example would be HasmMap and ConcurrentHashMap. Here, if you use the same HashMap with multiple threads you will surely get errors (such as if one thread itterates the Map entries while another one tries to modify it you'll get a concurrent modification exception) or if not errors at least a huge performance bottle neck, as the Map will do a lot of re-hashig as a consequence of having multiple writes sent from multiple threads. On the other hand, ConcurrentHashMap is very good for having one instance shared between multiple threads. You'll not get concurrent modification exceptions and the Map's performance is a lot better when multiple threads write to it at the same time.

Comment: In other words, synchronized blocks do not sync on the reference `_db` but the object that is referenced by it at the time the block tries to execute?

Comment: @riha I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Synchronized BLOCKS work using as lock the instance passed as argument. Synchronized METHODS lock on the instance of the class that has that method (and is equivalent to "synchronized(this)" blocks). Synchronized STATIC METHODS use the encompasing class as lock

Comment: Yes, thanks. Before, I thought synchronized blocks lock on the reference passed, not the object instance that's assigned to it. That's actually pretty stupid now that I think of it... Oh and thanks for clearing up that `Connection` is not thread safe. I wasn't really aware of that.